# Documents & Data usage in my game

Tags: storage, documents, video-ads

I have created a word game and I checked the app size which is 42MB. On iPhone it also shows Documents & Data 74MB. Looks like the ads which I am caching is using that much storage. Or could it be something else? Is there any solution to cleanup? Not sure if I am missed something.
Don't the video ads release memory after playing? I am using AdColony and Unity.
Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a lot of reasons why the app size is big. Could be due to many textures (compressed/uncompressed) in your resources or referenced in your project. As far as ads are concerned, an ad file will almost always first download on your device before being played.

It is not neccessary that they will unload immediately after playing. Suppose AdColony only has one ad that matches your setup (ad-filters) on their site. Instead of downloading a 40mb ad every time you request, it will download it and keep it until it invalidates the ad. When the cache clears depends on the logic of the plugin and from observation, ads tend to stay for a good period.